# Run line of text in terminal from rtf file

Tags: macos, terminal, rtf

If I have some simple text in a .rtf file (called `test_file.rtf`), how can I run this in terminal?

For example if I have `cd Documents/Movies` written in this file, I don't want to have to open the file, copy that line, paste it into terminal, then hit enter to get into the Movies folder. I just want to simply 'run' `test_file.rtf` and then I will be in Movies folder.

Is there a simple way to just call this without loads of ammendments to my setup or to the simple rtf file? Essentially just a word to type in to say 'run this command'?

Comment: What environment is this? Window or Linux?

Comment: Macbook, macOS Big Sur version 11.2

Comment: Try source test_file.rtf

Comment: get an error of 'command not found'